# everlasting sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to configure PHP sessions to never expire? I currently have the default 24 minutes set in php.ini - I could whack this up to a couple of weeks or something like that but I was wondering if I can set them to infinite lifetime?

I want to achieve a similar effect to Stackoverflow's: I never have to log in here. Is this achieved on SO with a never-expiring session or some other means?

Also, as a secondary question: How do the expired session files get cleaned up? If someone creates a session and never returns, which process is cleaning up their expired file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, what appears to be an everlasting session is two things: a session, which expires pretty soon, and a very long-life cookie containing an auto-login token.

There's a great series of responses on sessions and logging-in contained in this StackOverflow question: **[The Definitive Guide To Website Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477578#477578)**

Regarding your question about when sessions are cleaned up, there are several [php.ini settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) for controlling when the garbage collection for sessions is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP both allows and encourages you to create your own session data storage handlers, there is no single correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to secondary question

Session file cleanup is controlled by the following 3 php.ini settings:

- session.gc_probability (default value 1)
- session.gc_divisor (default value 100)
- session.gc_maxlifetime (specified the age after which the session is considered as garbage)

First 2 settings specify the probability of the garbage collection process being started at *session start* (before or at the very beginning of your script execution, depending on how you have set things up)

In default configuration there is a 1% probability then that this happens. If it does, then files that are older than maxlifetime are cleaned.

As for your first question - why not write a custom session handler, that stores sessions inside the database (if you have one). That way you can see and control the sessions right from inside the database. Handy :)